# Syntax highlight on nginx for every cpp without human interaction

Tags: c++, nginx, webserver, highlight

Basically, I've a webserver, where I stated in my nginx conf, to show every .cpp as plain text - but I want to make a syntax highlight for more readability.

Any idea how could I proceed?

I want to use google highlights, so any idea about how to insert before an html file before and after every .cpp would suffice.

I thought and tried in the far past using header and footer tags in nginx conf, with no luck whatsoever. 
Thanks in advance!

cheers!

Comment: While it could probably be done by the web-server, it usually isn't. Instead it's usually up to the content delivery framework or system to do this.

Comment: There is no content delivery framework on the server whatsoever. Only fancyindex is on for viewing files.

Comment: Nginx itself can't do syntax hilighting, you must either use a server side language like PHP to serve a html file with syntax hilight or use a js plugin to hilight on the client side

Comment: That's my question basically - how can I add a js/php file without human interaction before every .cpp file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was already pointed out, Nginx is not quite suitable for generating HTML documents by itself. Usually this is a job for a server-side processing language like PHP or Perl. However, there are several ways of solving the problem solely with Nginx.

The first obvious choice would be to use a server-side processing language from within Nginx. There are at least three optional modules for three different languages ([Perl](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html), [Lua](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/) and a dialect of [Javascript](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/nginScript/)) that could be used for that.

The problem with this approach is that these modules are rarely available by default, and in many cases you will have to build Nginx manually to enable any of them. Sometimes it can be painful, because as soon as you get your own custom build of Nginx, you will have to support and upgrade it yourself.

There is, however, another option, which involves [SSI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html). It might not be the prettiest solution but it will work. And unlike above-mentioned modules, the SSI support comes with almost every distribution of Nginx. My bet is, your Nginx can do SSI out of the box, without having to compile anything.

So, the configuration goes like this:

```
# Define a special virtual location for your cpp files
location ~* \.(cpp|h)$ {
    # Unless a GET parameter 'raw' is set with 'yes'
    if ($arg_raw = 'yes') {
        break;
    }

    # Redirect all the requests for *.cpp and *.h files to another location @js
    try_files @js @js;
}

location @js {
    ssi on;                  # Enable SSI in this location
    default_type text/html;  # Tell the browser that what is returned is HTML

    # Generate a suitable HTML document with an SSI insertion
    return 200 '<!DOCTYPE html>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.9.0/styles/default.min.css">
                <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.9.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
                <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
                <pre><code class="cpp"><!--# include virtual="$uri?raw=yes" --></code></pre>';
}
```

Now here is what happens if you request some *.cpp file in your browser:

1. The request goes to the first location, because the URI ends with `cpp`.
2. Then it is redirected to the second location `@js`, because there is no GET parameter `raw` in your request.
3. In the second location the SSI template is generated with [return](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) and then immediately processed by the SSI engine because of `ssi on`.
4. The `include virtual="$uri?raw=yes"` tells the SSI engine to make another request (subrequest) from within Nginx to the originally requested file (the internal variable [$uri](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_uri) stores the original URI, that is the web path to your cpp file). The difference between the request from your browser and the subrequest made by Nginx is `?raw=yes`.
5. The subrequest again is handled by the first location, but it never goes to the second one, because of the `raw` GET parameter. In this case the raw contents of the cpp file is returned as a response to the subrequest.
6. The SSI engine combines this response with the rest of the template and returns the result to the browser. Additionally, [default_type](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#default_type) tells the browser to render the result as an HTML document.

You can see an example of the output [here](https://www.reveron.ru/static/files/example.cpp). I used [this](https://highlightjs.org) highlighting library for this example. You can change it with whatever you prefer simply modifying the SSI template.

Comment: That's perfect. Exactly suits my needs! Tanks Ivan! :)